# Logical Expression and truth table

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

So I'm trying to write out a logical expression and a truth table for the function: **if s then p else q**.

The problem I'm having is I don't know how to represent that function in logic. I mean I know in most programming languages the code would look something like this ---> if **s ? p : q**. In other words if **s** output **p** otherwise output **q**. But how would that look in logic? I tried to come up with a truth table first but I'm not sure how to do that without the logical expression.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know a logic operator for "if s then p"?

Comment: @Dre Wouldn't it be **s -> p**

Comment: What about (s ⟹ p) ^ (¬s ⟹ q) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your truth table, make 7 columns S, P, Q, $\lnot S$, S and P, $\lnot S$ and Q, and finally (S and P) or ($\lnot$ S and Q)

The last column corresponds to what you want:

(S and P) OR ($\lnot$ S and Q)

Comment: Just wondering why do I need two S columns? Wouldn't it be 6 rows? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Only one S column, the other is "not S"

Comment: @David you need to use \lnot, not \not in LaTeX notation to get the correct symbol

Comment: Oh, I see. Ok thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You know that "if s then p" is $s \implies p$, can you think of a way to combine that and elementary logical operators to get "if s then p else q"

Comment: See I'm not quite sure how to represent that for some reason. I think it may be something like: (s -> p) OR (s -> q). Or it could be    (s -> p) OR q. Or using De Morgan's law s -> p can be rewritten as (-s OR p) and then I'm assuming it is (-s OR P) OR Q. But I think I'm approaching this wrong.